# vertical-align не работает с img

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему вот такой код, не делает изображения по центру?

```html
<div style="height: 200px;">
  <img src="img/crystal.png" style="height: 40px; vertical-align: central;" />
</div>
```

При этом, если вместо изображения будет текст, то все работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это связано с механикой работы свойства `vertical-align: middle;` c помощью него выравниваеться элемены которые стоят в строке относительно друг друга.
Если Вам нужно выровнять картинку относительно центра родительского блока, воспользуйтесь `flexbox`:

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: а если у меня height стоит auto, можно ли как-то тут разместить без использования margin?

Comment: Да, можно `align-items: center;` и `justify-content: center;`

Comment: не знаю почему, но не работает, мне нужно именно вертикально по центру

Comment: А вы на родителя вешаете? Вот пример: https://jsbin.com/rexosisubo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: да, делал все верно, но почему-то идет смещения немного вверх, убрал padding и margin вообще у всех элементов, и все равно, расстояния над и под изображениям разные (примерно 15-20 пикселей разницы)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте исправить на `vertical-align: middle; display: inline;`

http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align

Answer (score 3):

Первая [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) из гугла говорит:

> Свойство CSS  vertical-align описывает вертикальное позиционирование строчных элементов (inline) или ячеек таблицы (table-cell).

Обратите внимание: **строчных элементов** и **ячеек таблицы**. Блок `div` по умолчанию, как это не странно, является блочным элементом. Поэтому и не работает.